# libbpf: failed to guess program from ELF section 'filter'

Tags: ebpf, libbpf

After compilation of the ebpf code, when loading it into the kernel it is showing an error.

Program section:

```
SEC("filter")
int icmp_timestamp(struct __sk_buff *skb) {
    // Load the Ethernet protocol
    void *data_end = (void *)(long)skb->data_end;
    void *data = (void *)(long)skb->data;
    struct ethhdr *eth = data;
```

Error:

libbpf: failed to guess program type from ELF section 'filter'
libbpf: supported section(type) names are: socket sk_reuseport/migrate sk_reuseport kprobe+ uprobe+ uprobe.s+ kretprobe+ uretprobe+ uretprobe.s+ kprobe.multi+ kretprobe.multi+ ksyscall+ kretsyscall+ usdt+ tc classifier action tracepoint+ tp+ raw_tracepoint+ raw_tp+ raw_tracepoint.w+

How to overcome this problem. Thank you for the solution

Comment: I've answered below. I'm wondering however where you got this `SEC("filter")` from. I saw several people posting questions with this same syntax.

Comment: I want to filtrate packets that need to be passed or dropped. That's the reason I used SEC("filter")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libbpf is telling you that **the section name should point to the type of BPF program you want this to be**. For example, if you want to later attach this program to an XDP hook you need a BPF program of type XDP with:

```
SEC("xdp")
```

The list of supported section names can be found at https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf/blob/v1.2.2/src/libbpf.c#L8894. A `+` at the end means that it can either be the exact `SEC("kprobe")` or well-formed `SEC("kprobe/extras")` with a proper `/` separator.

Comment: I want to attach this program to xdp hook later. The change has worked.